# Implement queue priority in rabbitmq

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, priority-queue

I'm using rabbitmq in my application. There are 2 queues for different kind of requests. On consumer side i've set up a few listeners that are listening to  these 2 queues .Whenever a message comes up, these listeners start processing it. i need to make sure that messages in one queue are treated as high priority item than the messages in other queue.

The problem is AMQP queues are FIFO queues. If a low priority message comes before the high priority message, that will be consumed first .

i need to do the implementation in such a way that if any listener gets free, it should serve the high priority queue first irrespective of the time of arrival of the message in high priority queue.

For example there are 3 requests in low priority queue and 2 listeners at consumer end. Since there is no request in high priority queue, both listeners take the messages from low priority queue and process them. Meanwhile, another message gets queued in high priority queue. At this point of time, there is one request in high priority and one in low priority.  In my current implementation, the available listener is consuming the  message from low priority queue first .

I'd like to know how can i set the queue priority such that the listener always processes the messages in high priority queue first

Please help me
FYI The publisher is a Grails application and the consumer is a Java App and at grails end, i'm using rabbitmq plugin to publish the messages.
Thanks!

Comment: heve you seen this https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html ?

Comment: @Gabriele yes i saw that. In this implementation we need to publish messages with priority and as i mentioned the publisher is a grails application . I'm using Grails 2.2.2 and grails rabbitmq-plugin. There is no provision of adding message priority in this plugin. there is another rabbitmq-native plugin in grails which sets the priority of a message but that works with >3.0 grails version and i cant upgrade Grails.
So i'm looking for a solution in which i can just set the priority of a queue and all messages published to that queue should be given high priority